# what is the purpose of the ng-template wrapped by ng-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect, ng-template

I saw many example of ng-select in which ng-select wraps a ng-template, as shown below.

```
    <ng-select
  [items]="cities"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
  bindLabel="name"
  bindValue="name"
>
  <ng-template
    ng-option-tmp
    let-item="item"
    let-item$="item$"
    let-index="index"
  >
    {{ item.name }}
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

I try to remove the ng-template and the result looks same as ng-template not removed.
May I know what is the purpose of ng-template in this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: ng-option-tmp - what do?

Answer (score 1):

ng-select don't need ng-template only If you have simple use case, you can omit items array and bind options directly in html using ng-option component.